# The Alias directive ... will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm getting this warning from Apache:

```
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/foo.conf at line 10 will 
probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

However the Alias overlaps on a completely different virtual host.

Might this be caused because one alias is on a name-based virtual host while the other alias is on an IP-based virtual host?

Everything is working fine, just the warning is a bit annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning was because the Alias directive was part of a include file, causing the Alias to be applied globally, rather than on a single virtual host.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for that. I was making the same mistake.